# Dimensions error using BCEWithLogitsLoss PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have a problem with dimensions which appear in this line of code `loss = self.cross_entropy(preds, labels)`. Error looks like this: `RuntimeError: output with shape [32, 1] doesn't match the broadcast shape [32, 2]`.

I don't know what is wrong because when I do: `labels.shape` and `preds.shape` they give me both: `torch.Size([32, 1])`.

I do binary classificator for opinions about products.

My preds variable looks like this inside: `tensor([[0.9629], [1.0000], [0.9965], [0.9881], [0.9744], [0.8138], [0.8554], [0.8460], [0.6731], [0.9852], [0.9993], [0.7753], [0.7943], [0.7197], [0.9878], [0.7717], [1.0000], [0.9850], [0.9685], [0.6256], [0.7840], [0.5589], [0.4942], [0.8766], [1.0000], [0.2887], [0.8176], [0.9193], [0.4488], [0.8078], [0.8877], [1.0000]], grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward0>)`

And my labels variable looks like this inside: `tensor([[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.],[0.]])`.

This is my achitecture:

```
class _2FC(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size=100, hidden_size=512):
        super(_2FC, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)
        return x
```

and this is my training code:

```
class BasicTrainer():
    def __init__(self, model, weights, train_dataloader, val_dataloader, file_name='saved_weights', device='cpu', epochs=100):
        self.device = torch.device(device)
        self.model = model.to(self.device)
        self.optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
        self.cross_entropy = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(weight=weights.to(self.device)).to(self.device)
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.train_dataloader = train_dataloader
        self.val_dataloader = val_dataloader
        self.file_name = file_name

    def _train(self):
        self.model.train()
        total_loss, total_accuracy = 0, 0
        total_preds=[]

        for step, batch in enumerate(self.train_dataloader):     
            batch = [r.to(self.device) for r in batch]
            sent_id, labels = batch
            self.model.zero_grad()

            labels = labels.unsqueeze(1).float()

            preds = self.model(sent_id)

            loss = self.cross_entropy(preds, labels)
            total_loss = total_loss + loss.item()

            loss.backward()
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.model.parameters(), 1.0)
            self.optimizer.step()
            preds=preds.detach().cpu().numpy()
            total_preds.append(preds)
        
        avg_loss = total_loss / len(self.train_dataloader)
        total_preds = np.concatenate(total_preds, axis=0)
        return avg_loss, total_preds
```

Comment: Meh, why did you use BCEWithLogitsLoss? in this case you applied sigmoid, you dont even have logits. Use BCELoss instead.

Comment: What should I do to use BCEWithLogitsLoss correctly? Just change sigmoid to softmax?

Comment: No, dont use any activation función.